# Adaptec ASR-7805 bios password

Tags: bios, raid, passwords

I would like to set the password for Adaptec ASR-7805 BIOS utility, which you access by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, right when the system boots, in order to prevent possibility of unauthorized access for managing/erasing my arrays? I have checked inside of BIOS but didn't find anything that would work around?

Comment: Not sure what your issue is. Are you able to see the Adaptec BIOS screen? Is the issue you don't see anywhere to set the password?

Comment: Yes, this is correct! I don't see it anywhere to set it?

Comment: Are you sure this card supports this? The documentation here: http://download.adaptec.com/pdfs/user_guides/adaptec_raid_controller_iug_12_2012.pdf doesn't list anything about BIOS passwords.

Comment: Well.. This is a problem! I thought, that maybe there could be other way around, e.g. through Adaptec Software and that someone already tried to protect controller's BIOS this way. If it's not it will be hard to believe!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a ticket with *Adaptec tech-support* and got a reply saying that **BIOS passwords are not supported**. In other words you can not set a password for *Adaptec ASR-7805 BIOS*.

Which is sad and unreasonable for me!